How to get Azure Functions (Typescript) HttpRequest raw body as string (for Stripe web hook verification)
I'm trying to verify a Stripe web hook call in my Typescript v4 Azure Function App.
I successfully receive the call from Stripe, with the signature from the header, but I can't work out how to get the unmodified body from the HttpRequest object.  The error that I get is:
[Error]   ⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed. No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? 
 If a webhook request is being forwarded by a third-party tool, ensure that the exact request body, including JSON formatting and new line style, is preserved.

I've tried parsing the body.json, and using a package like raw-body (which just crashes the function with no error), and feeding the req.body.toString() ReadableStream into Buffer with no success (see examples below).
This did not work:
const requestBody: any = await request.json();
const requestBodyString = JSON.stringify(requestBody);

This did not work:
var getRawBody = require('raw-body')
const rawBodyBuffer: any = await request.body.toString();
const requestBodyString = getRawBody(rawBodyBuffer);

This did not work:
const requestBodyString = request.text();

Has anyone successfully capture the raw body of an Azure Function (Typescript) and verified it with Stripe using the signature?  If so can you share an example of you code please?

OK, first rule of coding is post your problem in SO.  Guaranteed that you'll solve your own question in under an hour!
So I was putting the request.text() into a variable, and that did not work.  But what does work is passing request.text() directly into the call to stipe.webhooks.constructEvent() like this:
    // Only verify the event if you have an endpoint secret defined.
    if (webhookState?.secret) {
        try {
            event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
                await request.text(),
                signature,
                webhookState?.secret
            );
        } catch (err) {
            Log.error(`⚠️  A1 Webhook signature verification failed.`, err.message);
            return {
                status: 400,
            };
        }

        Log.error(`✳️  Webhook signature verification succeeded!`);
    }

Now I'll do a happy dance!
